# Express, fetching data from pons API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch-api

I am new to express and I try to fetch data from Pons API: https://en.pons.com/p/files/uploads/pons/api/api-documentation.pdf

Here is my file:

```
const express = require("express");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

const app = express();

app.get("/", async (req, res, next) => {
  const answer = await fetch(
    "https://api.pons.com/v1/dictionary?q=dom&l=depl",
    {
      method: "get",
      headers: {
        "X-Secret":
          "XXX",
      },
    }
  )
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((json) => console.log(json))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
});

app.listen(5000);
```

In my console I only see this:

> [ { lang: 'pl', hits: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
> { lang: 'de', hits: [ [Object] ] } ]

I would like to get translations in German for the word "dom".
Can somebody please tell me what do I have wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything wrong. You just need some additional code to access the Objects in the response, which is a regular JavaScript object, but `console.log()` is just not printing it all. The translation you are looking for is contained somewhere in there. Just be aware that there can be multiple responses as the same word can have different meanings or can be of different word classes (noun, verb, adjective, etc.)

What you can do to get a better understanding of the objects is to use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to print the whole structure. For example:

```js
.then((json) => console.log(JSON.stringify(json, null, 2)))
```

Note: The third paramter `2` means that an indentation of 2 spaces will be used.

Comment: Your answer is good to grasp how to catch a json string, but not helpful for the parsing of the `pons` api result.

Answer (score 0):

#### My approach to the Pons Api on the server

```
const utils = require('./lib/utils')

app.get("/dic/:word", (req, res, next) => {
utils.getLastLine('api_key', 1).then(key => {
key = key.split('=')[1]
var word = req.params.word
var translate = 'dees'
return fetch(
 `https://api.pons.com/v1/dictionary?q=${word}&l=${translate}`,{
  headers: { "X-Secret": key }}
)
    .then(res => res.json()).then(json => {
    var base = json[0].hits[0].roms[0]
    var wclass = base.wordclass
    var arab = base.arabs[0]
    var trans = arab.translations
    var firsttrans = trans[0].target
    var nrtrans = arab.translations.length
    res.json({ firsttrans, wclass, nrtrans, trans })
   })
 });
});
```

##### Requirements:

- Get a [Pons Api](https://en.pons.com/p/online-dictionary/developers/api) Key
- Be familiar with [`fetch Api`](https://blog.logrocket.com/fetch-api-node-js/) - recommended server-side

##### Further/Limits:

- It is a nested `fetch`
- See a [live example](https://tik9.herokuapp.com/public/further.html#dictionary)
- Code example is for development, not for production:

  - no server error catching in case of

    - no input
    - non-existing word
  - not all Api results are considered, just the first `hit`